# internal links in facebook app - doesn't work in IE

Tags: html, facebook, internet-explorer, iframe

I made a facebook app (well it's not done yet, but most of the stuff is done).. in the menu I'm using internal links like 'user/index.php' '../mailbox.php' etc.. In every browser it's working properly but in IE6, IE7, IE8 it doesn't. IE is redirecting to the host Canvas Callback URL.

any idea why ?

FIXED:
Fixed with using
`header('P3P:CP="HONK IDC DSP COR ADM DEVi TAIi PSA PSD IVAi IVDi CONi HIS OUR IND CNT"');`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is all what you need (from Facebook dev):

```
header('P3P: CP=HONK');
```