# Facebook authentication issue

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I'm getting a bit pissed off with Facebook's platform constantly changing, fragile structure, and lack of decent and up-to-date documentation.

Currently, I'm migrating an app from FBML now that it's deprecated to an iFrame app, and having issues authenticating. Currently, I have a global bootstrap script that is loaded upon each page view that contains the following pertaining to authentication:

```
// attempt to authenticate against Facebook platform
require dirname(__FILE__) . '/facebook.php';

$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => APP_ID,
    'secret' => SECRET,
    'cookie' => true
));

$session = $facebook->getSession();

$user = null;
if ($session) {
    try {
        $uid = $facebook->getUser();
        $user = $facebook->api('/me');
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException $e) {
        error_log($e);
    }
}

if (!$user) {
    $loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl(array(
        'req_perms' => 'email,user_likes',
        'next' => CANVAS_URL.'/'
    ));
    echo '<script>top.location.href="'.$loginUrl.'";</script>';
    exit;
}
```

This was put together based on examples in the official [Facebook PHP SDK](https://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) and developer's documentation, but when first loading the app is just goes around in a nasty redirect circle and I have no idea where to start debugging as I've nothing to refer to from Facebook.

Has any one got a working sample of authenticating a Facebook iFrame app, or can see something inherently wrong with the code snippet I have above?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Forgot to mention that it goes in a redirect loop with the above code, but if I remove the parameters array from `$facebook->getLoginUrl()` call then it eventually breaks out of the loop and out of Facebook itself, instead going to my canvas URL outside of Facebook's iFrame container. For example, the URL becomes `http://www.woohoobingo.com/facebookv2/?session={...}` instead of `http://apps.facebook.com/woohoobingo/`.

Comment: Did you try placing some statements on different lines so it gives you an idea from where the code is redirecting you.

Comment: I've tried echoing the value of `$loginUrl`, yes. Does redirecting to the same page that's invoking the authentication request break things though? I would have thought the SDK would pick up the token from the auth. request?

Comment: Which browser you are using? IE 8 and safari do not allow to store cookies from iframe. try using firefox first then if the problem solve let me know I can give you the solution for IE cookie storing problem.

Comment: Ah. I'm using Google Chrome, which uses WebKit. Would this be the issue?

Comment: header ('P3P: CP = "IDC DSP COR ADM DEVI TAII PSA PSD OUR Ivai IVDi CONI HIS IND CNT"');  Try to add this line at the top of the page. hope it works

Comment: It's patched it in Google Chrome, but Safari is still having a fit over it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [internal links in facebook app - doesn't work in IE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5851869/internal-links-in-facebook-app-doesnt-work-in-ie)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This line works for me

```
header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"');
```

But as you said it is not working in safari because it do not patch it to store cookies then you can use an alternative 
That turn off cookies

```
$facebook = new Facebook(array(
    'appId'  => APP_ID,
    'secret' => SECRET,
    'cookie' => false
));
```

and try to use the access token after authentication @access_token is the oauth access_token that gets passed to your canvas page in the initial POST request.

```
$facebook->api('/me?access_token='.$access_token);
```

Hope it works

Answer (score 2):

Cracked it. Used the following HTTP header at the top of my `index.php` file:

```
header('P3P: CP="IDC DSP COR CURa ADMa OUR IND PHY ONL COM STA"');
```

Comment: This is awesome :) I checked it at my end too works perfect. Thought the line I have given works for me but not works for my friends and the line you have provided me works for both of us :) Let me edit my answer too so the person who see this question will not confuse.